# Place a Bear Bet via Pancakeswap Predictions

Tags: contract-development, web3.py, abi, bsc, pancakeswap

I'm pretty new to using Python to interact with smart contracts. I've been trying to make a short and simple python script that will interact with Pancakeswap's prediction market contract and place a bear bet. From what I can understand, I'm supposed to use the `contract.functions.bearBet()` function to place my bet, but it seems like this only accepts one argument (my bet amount). When I place the transaction, I get an error on the blockchain that says `"Failed with error 'Bet is too early or too late'"`.

A little more digging and I've seen other examples use the current epoch along with the bet amount in the parameters, but I end up getting this error:

```
Could not identify the intended function with name `betBear`, positional arguments with type(s) `set` and keyword arguments with type(s) `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `betBear`: ['betBear(uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.
```

Here is the code I've been messing around with:

```
from web3 import Web3
import json

# Replace with the actual contract address and ABI
contract_address = '0x18B2A687610328590Bc8F2e5fEdDe3b582A49cdA'
abi = json.loads('[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_oracleAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_adminAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_operatorAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_intervalSeconds","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_bufferSeconds","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_minBetAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_oracleUpdateAllowance","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_treasuryFee","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"BetBear","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"BetBull","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Claim","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"roundId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"price","type":"int256"}],"name":"EndRound","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"roundId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"price","type":"int256"}],"name":"LockRound","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"admin","type":"address"}],"name":"NewAdminAddress","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"bufferSeconds","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"intervalSeconds","type":"uint256"}],"name":"NewBufferAndIntervalSeconds","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"minBetAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"NewMinBetAmount","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"NewOperatorAddress","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"oracle","type":"address"}],"name":"NewOracle","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"oracleUpdateAllowance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"NewOracleUpdateAllowance","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"treasuryFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"NewTreasuryFee","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Paused","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardBaseCalAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"treasuryAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RewardsCalculated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"StartRound","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"TokenRecovery","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"TreasuryClaim","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Unpaused","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MAX_TREASURY_FEE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"adminAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"betBear","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"betBull","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"bufferSeconds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"epochs","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"claim","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"claimTreasury","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"claimable","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"currentEpoch","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"executeRound","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisLockOnce","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisLockRound","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisStartOnce","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisStartRound","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"cursor","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"size","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getUserRounds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"components":[{"internalType":"enum PancakePredictionV2.Position","name":"position","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"claimed","type":"bool"}],"internalType":"struct PancakePredictionV2.BetInfo[]","name":"","type":"tuple[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"getUserRoundsLength","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"intervalSeconds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"ledger","outputs":[{"internalType":"enum PancakePredictionV2.Position","name":"position","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"claimed","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"minBetAmount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"operatorAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"oracle","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract AggregatorV3Interface","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"oracleLatestRoundId","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"oracleUpdateAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"recoverToken","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"refundable","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"rounds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"startTimestamp","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"lockTimestamp","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"closeTimestamp","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"lockPrice","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"closePrice","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"lockOracleId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"closeOracleId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"totalAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"bullAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"bearAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardBaseCalAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"oracleCalled","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_adminAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setAdmin","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_bufferSeconds","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_intervalSeconds","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setBufferAndIntervalSeconds","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_minBetAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setMinBetAmount","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_operatorAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setOperator","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_oracle","type":"address"}],"name":"setOracle","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_oracleUpdateAllowance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setOracleUpdateAllowance","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_treasuryFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setTreasuryFee","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"treasuryAmount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"treasuryFee","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"userRounds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]')

# Connect to the contract
bsc_node_url = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc_node_url))

contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)

# Set the epoch and amount
epoch = contract.functions.currentEpoch().call()

print(epoch)
amount = w3.to_wei('0.01', 'ether')

private_key = "XXXX"
account = w3.eth.account.from_key(private_key)

# Call the betBear function

transaction = contract.functions.betBear(amount).build_transaction({
    'from': account.address,
    'gas': 2000000,
    'gasPrice': w3.to_wei('5', 'gwei'),  # Adjust gas price accordingly
    'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address),
    
})



signed_transaction = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key)
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)

print(f"Transaction sent: {tx_hash.hex()}")
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. There are only one small error. The BetBear function actually tooks the "epoch" as input, not the "amount". You have to define "amount" in "value" when you buildTransaction.

Fix the code of call betBear function to this and it will successfully execute function.

```
transaction = contract.functions.betBear(epoch).build_transaction({
    'from': account.address,
    'gas': 2000000,
    'value': amount,
    'gasPrice': w3.to_wei('5', 'gwei'),  # Adjust gas price accordingly
    'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(account.address),
    
})
```

A small comment is that you can actually looks for the reason leads to the error: "Failed with error 'Bet is too early or too late" in the smart contract from this link (https://bscscan.com/address/0x18B2A687610328590Bc8F2e5fEdDe3b582A49cdA#code) at the code line number 832 as

```
function betBear(uint256 epoch) external payable whenNotPaused nonReentrant notContract {
    require(epoch == currentEpoch, "Bet is too early/late");
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes! That was it! I had no idea I had to use the 'value' parameter when creating the tx or that betbear was looking for the epoch only. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great to hear that. Glad for help.